# Firefox Add-on SDK: communicating objects between a sidebar and the main script

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-sidebar

I am hacking away at my first addon, so the problem I am running into probably has either an obvious solution or my general approach is flawed.

I am using the [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Add-ons/SDK). My `lib/main.js` contains an object `foo`. The `data` directory has the files `sidebar.html` and `sidebar.js`. I want to pass `foo` to the sidebar-script and then change the sidebar depending on the state of `foo`. In the minmal example I will just try to display the object.

Minimal example:

`main.js`:

```
var foo = {"a": "b", "c": "d"};
var bar = require("sdk/ui/sidebar").Sidebar({
    id: "sb",
    title: "foobar",
    url: "./sidebar.html"
});
bar.show();
```

`sidebar.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>        
        <div id="foo-here">
            <!-- to be modified by sidebar.js -->
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sidebar.js"></script>
</html>
```

`sidebar.js`:

```
var foodiv = document.getElementById("foo-here");
var str = "", o;
// magically get foo from main.js here
for (o in foo) {
    if (foo.hasOwnProperty(o)) {
        str += "[" + o + " is " + foo[o] + "]";
    }
}
foodiv.innerHTML = str;
```

The [sidebar docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_sidebar) explain how to listen for signals from the main script and call a function upon receiving a signal, but I can't figure out how to pass the object itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`port.emit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port#port.emit%28%29) API mentioned in the sidebar docs you have linked also takes a second argument to pass in objects.